# Use getproperty, setproperty and hasproperty instead of $

Tags: grails, groovy

I have something like this.

```
def temp = "field"
object."$temp" = "hi"
```

This works fine.
But can i use setproperty, getproperty and hasproperty somehow to implement the same.

Thanks

Comment: @WillP How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `object."$temp" = "hi"` with `object.setProperty(temp, "hi")`, and `object."$temp"` with `object.getProperty(temp)`. There is also the square bracket syntax:

```
e = new Expando()

def field = 'name'

e[field] = 'john doe' // set
assert e[field] == 'john doe' // get

e.setProperty(field, 'foo') // set
assert e.getProperty(field) == 'foo' // get

if (!e.hasProperty('bar')) { // has property
    e['bar'] = 'my bar'
}

assert e.getProperty('bar') == 'my bar'
```